# Datatable View Data from JSON API

Tags: javascript, arrays, codeigniter, datatables, jquery-select2

I would like to view data from the controller which is contained JSON formatted array, but unfortunately, I'm getting stuck here. The scenario is just like this.

I have a table that used Datatable grid, I populated the row of the table with default 20 rows, with each of all contain dropdown select2 and it works fine. And the problem comes when I want to preview specific data on my default table with 20 rows.

[image]

Here is my controller that provides json array triggered by specific data that the user wants to:

```
public function getSpecData($filter="get")
{
    $filter  = str_replace('_','/', $filter);
    $query   ="select * from tb_detail where subject='".$filter."'";
    $arrData = $this->db->query($query)->result();
    print_r(json_encode($arrData,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
}
```

And the output of my controller was:

```
[{"NO": "1","DESCRIPTION":"Mathematic","SUBJECT":"Praveen Jordan","TOTAL":"95"},{"NO": "2","DESCRIPTION":"Physic","SUBJECT":"Praveen Jordan","TOTAL":"90"}]
```

My detail view that should handle this JSON was:

```
<input type="hidden" id="f_status" style="width:100%" name="f_status" value="<?php echo isset($f_subject)?$f_subject:""; ?>" class="form-control" required readonly>
<input type="hidden" id="f_status" style="width:100%" name="f_status" value="<?php echo isset($f_status)?$f_status:""; ?>" class="form-control" required readonly>
<table id="tb_detail" class="stripe row-border">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>No</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Subject</th>
    <th>Total</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php 
    $strDetail="";
    for($i=0;$i<20;$i++){
        $strDetail.="<tr>";
        $strDetail.="<td style=\"text-align:right;\">".($i+1).".</td>";
        $strDetail.="<td><select id='txtDesc[]".$i."' name='txtDesc[]".$i."' value=\"\" class=\"desc\" style=\"width:500px;\"></select></td>";
        $strDetail.="<td><select name='txtSub[]".$i."' class=\"sub\" value=\"\" style=\"width:200px;\"></select></td>";
        $strDetail.="<td><input name='txtTot[]".$i."' class=\"tot\" value=\"\" style=\"width:200px;\"></select></td>";
        $strDetail.="</tr>";
    }
    echo $strDetail;
?>
</tbody>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
    selectedId.push(document.getElementById("f_status").value);
    selectedId.push(document.getElementById("f_subject").value);
    var subject = selectedId[1];
    var table = $('#tb_detail').DataTable( {
            scrollY:        "400px",
            scrollX:        true,
            scrollCollapse: true,
            paging:         false,
            bInfo        : false,
            fixedColumns:   {
                leftColumns: 2,
                rightColumns: 1
            }
    });
    $('.tot').number( true, 0, '.', ',' );
    $(".desc").select2({
        ajax: {
            url: '<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/C_index/getLookupSelect2/desc',
            dataType: 'json'
        }
    });
    $(".sub").select2({
        ajax: {
            url: '<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/C_index/getLookupSelect2/sub',
            dataType: 'json'
        }
    });
    if (selectedId[0] == 'VIEW') {
        $.ajax({
            type  : 'ajax',
            url   : '<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/C_index/getSpecData/'+subject,
            dataType : 'json',
            success : function(data){
                var i;
                for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                        $('.desc').val(data[i].DESCRIPTION);
                        $('.sub').val(data[i].SUBJECT);
                        $('.tot').val(data[i].TOTAL);
                }    
            }
        });
    }
  }
</script>
```

My desired output is how should I do to make the JSON array was load in my Datatable.

Anyone can solve this, I'm stuck with this about two days.

Comment: could you show what `console.dir(data)` outputs (in your ajax success)?

Comment: @Vickel [{"NO": "1","DESCRIPTION":"Mathematic","SUBJECT":"Praveen Jordan","TOTAL":"95"},{"NO": "2","DESCRIPTION":"Physic","SUBJECT":"Praveen Jordan","TOTAL":"90"}]
here is output console.log(data)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ajax to get your data, then the datatable is likely being initialised before it has any data in it. You would be better off using the DataTables ajax option to populate your table. [See this example](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html). Make sure to click on the Ajax tab to see how the data is formatted. You need an extra pair of curly braces around your square ones and the name "data" for your array of objects. If you later want to refresh your datatable using different parameters use

```
tableObject.ajax.url('new-url-here').load()
```

[Link for reload example](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.url().load())